# Adding file type options to input file

Tags: html, file, input, mime-types

I am building a tool that you can upload different files using

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

I set multiple attr because the user only can choose a set of file if they are of same type.

The question is: How can I add options to selected element on the image?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmIJX.png

I have tried adding an `accept` attribute as "image/*,video/*" but they appear under a only element on combobox, I would like that they appear on separated options.

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAOnNNYmA8hF_IVz3CX3wpTRvRiymBkUxwY

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you are asking If you are asking for separate(order) files by file type its not possible **its a browser property** and if you asking about selecting  files of different types. 
 Try this...

```html
<input type='file' accept=".jpg,.png" muliple/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I agree with you that setting comma separated extension file you can select diferent type of file, but I want appear on separated options on upload windows.

Comment: not getting your requirement .if you want to provide separate option of select group(type) of file you can make it dynamic by `js`.. if its not what you asking, try to explain your requirements if its not solved.

Comment: yeah! this could resolve my problem. Do you know any js-lib to add news entries to select group(type) of upload file form? Thanks you very much

Comment: Sorry I don't know any such plugin.. and if this code resolved your problem please accept it.